# Build Success | Not Getting any error in Maven Project in Eclipse but nothing is happening

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I created a new Maven Project in Eclipse. When I try to run any method annotated with Test, the content inside it does not get executed. I checked all the build paths etc but did not find anything wrong. I deleted and re-created the project. Closed and Re-opened Eclipse. Below is the code and Console Log. There is no error in Console Log also. Please let me know if any other information is required

Not sure what I did wrong but it was working fine few hours back

**Note:** I am using TestNG to run the tests

**Code:**

```
package testPackage;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testClass {


    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

**Console Log:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building framework 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ framework ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ framework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ framework ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ framework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ framework ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.218 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-01T13:01:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I changed the name of Test class from framework to TestClass and it started working. I read somewhere (don't remember though) that TestNG class name should contain "Test" so as to be identified by it as TestNG Test class.

Answer (score 0):

It did run for me after making the below changes to the code

```
package testPackage;

import org.junit.Test;

public class testClass {


@Test
public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

}

Below is dependency used in pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention (in the text) that I am using TestNG and not JUnit. I will modify the question.